# How to submit form fields when they are not always rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a table component that dynamically renders only the rows that are currently visible (for performance reasons). For example if there are 1000 rows in the table and the user scrolls down halfway, I only render `<tr>` elements for rows 490-510. [Here's a visualization](https://clusterize.js.org/img/table_example.gif) if my description isn't clear.

**Question:** since the table rows can contain input fields—how can I ensure all fields are submitted with the `<form>`?

Use case:

1. User fills in a field in the first row of a table, `<input name=firstName_row1>`
2. User scrolls down such that only rows 20-40 are in the DOM
3. User submits the page without `<input name=firstName_row1>` in the DOM
4. Form submission does not include the value of `firstName_row1`

Some ideas:

1. Maintain a sister element `<input type=hidden>` for each table input and write values to both inputs

   - This guarantees the form submission will include all data, however there's lots of extra overhead from creating/updated additional DOM elements.
2. Track all inputs' values in memory until `form.onsubmit` fires, then generate `<input>` elements for all "missing" fields so they're included in the submission

   - There's still some DOM overhead, but I'd only need to create `n` new elements for `n` fields (instead of `2n` like the first option). Also, I'm not sure if I can reliably hijack `form.onsubmit` in every scenario—some other event handler could call `event.preventDefault()` and manually submit the form before this function runs.

Any other ideas?

My environment: the server is using Java (a few different frameworks) and I'm rendering the table with ReactJS. The data for the table, including the form fields' names and values, are defined in a JSON object by the server at page load. The server expects a traditional POST with `key1=value1` etc, not a JSON object or other representation of the data.